# How do I only total columns with numeric values on a new row? (Unsuccessful ROLLUP attempts)

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query results brings back a number of things, names, titles, aggregates, counts, etc. 
I only need a TOTAL ROW at the bottom for the last four columns:

```
AE  Client  Priority    Contract    LineNumber  Zone    Network Days    Time Parameter  Total Spots Required    Cost Per Spot   Required Rev
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  37  Atlanta AMC     MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       38           1           1           1
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  40  Atlanta AMC     MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       38           1           2           3
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  253 Atlanta ESPN    MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       33           5           3           5
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  256 Atlanta ESPN    MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       33           3           4           7
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  391 Atlanta GOLF    MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       35           1           5           9
Doe, John   Dummy Client    2   153370  412 Atlanta HALL    MTWTFSS      19:00 - 00:00       42           3           6           11
                                                                                            219           14         21           36
```

I keep trying to use the ROLLUP() or WITH ROLLUP but it then separates my lines out. I'm providing my whole query because I don't want something small to be what's messing me up and miss it by summarizing it.

```
Set DATEFIRST 1
SELECT
    AE.LastName+', '+AE.FirstName as 'AE',
    Client.Name as 'Client',
    Eventmaster.PriorityID as 'Priority',
    Conline.ConID as 'Contract',
    Conline.LineNum as 'LineNumber',
    Zone.Name as 'Zone',
    Network.Name as 'Network',
    ((CASE
        WHEN Conline.monday = '1'
            THEN 'M'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Tuesday = '1'
            THEN 'T'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Wednesday = '1'
            THEN 'W'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Thursday = '1'
            THEN 'T'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Friday = '1'
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Saturday = '1'
            THEN 'S'
            ELSE '-'
    END)+
    (CASE
        WHEN Conline.Sunday = '1'
            THEN 'S'
            ELSE '-'
    END)) as 'Days',
    (Left(Convert(Time, DATEADD(ss,Conline.StartTime, 0),0),5))+' - '+(Left(Convert(Time, DATEADD(ss,Conline.StopTime, 0),0),5)) as 'Time Parameter',
    Conline.TotalSpots as 'Total Spots',
    COUNT(EventMaster.Status) as 'Required',
    Conline.Cost as 'Cost Per Spot',
    Conline.Cost * count(eventmaster.status) as 'Required Rev'
FROM EventMaster
    inner join Conline on
    EventMaster.ConlineID = Conline.ConlineID
    inner join Contract on
    Conline.ConID = Contract.ConID
    inner join Zone on
    Conline.ZoneID = Zone.ZoneID
    inner join Network on
    Conline.NetworkID = Network.NetworkID
    inner join AE on
    Contract.AEID = AE.AEID
    inner join Client on
    Contract.ClientID = Client.ClientID

WHERE
    Conline.StartDate >= 19862
    and Conline.StopDate <= 19889
    and EventMaster.Status = 'R'
    and Network.Name NOT IN ('iATT', 'XCSV', 'XCSB','ICOX', 'ISYN', 'ICHT', 'LO3FLO', 'LO3HUNT', 'LO96', 'LOFE', 'INFO', 'IFXN', 'DMAN', 'SMS','VODT','RRR', 'RFI', 'LO', 'NPRD', 'CONT', 'PROD', 'RETL', 'VHXB', 'WEBO', 'INFOMERC','MISC-PKG','WEBB', 'VHXL','AUTO', 'CRWL', 'FEAT', 'LA 46', 'LEASE2', 'LO Knox')
    --and Eventmaster.ClientID <> '7777'
    and EventMaster.PriorityID = '2'
    and totalspots > '0'
    and EventMaster.Deleted <> '1'
GROUP BY
    AE.LastName,
    AE.FirstName,
    Client.Name,
    Eventmaster.PriorityID,
    Conline.ConID,
    Conline.LineNum,
    Zone.Name,
    Network.Name,
    Conline.TotalSpots,
    Conline.Monday,
    Conline.Tuesday,
    Conline.Wednesday,
    Conline.Thursday,
    Conline.Friday,
    Conline.Saturday,
    Conline.Sunday,
    Conline.StartTime,
    Conline.StopTime,
    conline.cost
ORDER BY
    AE.LastName,
    Conline.ConID,
    Zone.Name
SET DATEFIRST 7
```

It looks like it might have been trying to give me a total for every Conline.LineNum right below each line, but I need a total for the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by union clause. But union is only applicable with same no of attributes so you hav to use another blank values as well. Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT YOUR PREVIOUS QUERY
UNION
SELECT SUM(FIRST_COL), SUM(SECOND_COL), SUM(THIRD_COL), SUM(FOURTH_COL),
       NULL,NULL,NULL,...........
```

I anm not sure but I think this approach can solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to treat my first set of results as a table to pull from? How would I do that?
(edit: I can't have an aggregate of an aggregate so I wasn't sure how else to do that sum)

Comment: I realized that in my second SELECT I wouldn't need to include all the defining factors of each line, so by removing THOSE I basically create a SUM without using SUM. Hope that makes sense. For some reason I'm not getting the correct SUM of my TotalSpots, though, so I'm checking on that.